# Edit or remove facet labels of Seaborn displot

Tags: python, plot, seaborn

My question is about removing the facet labels from a `displot()`. I feel like they should be an attribute of the plot object but I can't quite dig them out/set them. Maybe I'm going about it all wrong.

I've got a faceted histogram plot. But I plan on incorporating this as one of many plots and so there won't be enough space in the final image to include the facet details in their current location, so I'd like to remove them from the subplot.

Code from the seaborn displot docs:

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.set_theme(style="darkgrid")
df = sns.load_dataset("penguins")
sns.displot(
    df, x="flipper_length_mm", col="species", row="sex",
    binwidth=3, height=3, facet_kws=dict(margin_titles=True),
)
```

This produces the plot:

[image]

I'd like to remove the entire `species = ...` from the facet titles.

Comment: Do you mean the entire `species = variable` or just `species =`?

Comment: The entire label (`species=variable`). I'll edit the q.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the method `sns.FacetGrid.set_titles` to turn off (or change the labels of) column and row titles.

I would caution against this, unless you are setting the `col_order` parameter so that you know which axes belongs to each particular variable.

```py
import seaborn as sns

sns.set_theme(style="darkgrid")
df = sns.load_dataset("penguins")

g = sns.displot(
    df, x="flipper_length_mm", col="species", row="sex",
    binwidth=3, height=3, facet_kws=dict(margin_titles=True),
)
g.set_titles(col_template="")
# This will also remove the row labels
# g.set_titles(col_template="", row_template="")
```

[image: Histogram with column titles removed.]

---

When not using `margin_titles` using `g.set_titles(template="")` will remove the entire top title.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.set_theme(style="darkgrid")
df = sns.load_dataset("penguins")
s=sns.displot(
    df, x="flipper_length_mm", col="species", row="sex",
    binwidth=3, height=3, facet_kws=dict(margin_titles=True),
)

s.set_titles("{col_name}");
```